# How to simplify the following PHP PDO connection codes?

Tags: php

```
class ActionWires{

public static function _checkExistDate($array){
    try{
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM wires WHERE fdate = ?";
          $state = pdoConnect::_connect() ->prepare($sql);
        $state->execute($array);
        return $state->fetch()?true:false;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "database connection fail".$e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
}

public static function _showWires($array){
    try{
        $sql = "SELECT id,wname,fdate,fname,fpath,caption,category FROM wires WHERE fdate = ?";
        $state = pdoConnect::_connect() ->prepare($sql);
        $state->execute($array);
        return $state->fetchAll();
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "database connection fail".$e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
}
```

There are lot of codes are the same. The main difference is sql query and return value. Are there any suggestion to minimize the same codes.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be hard to minimise this completely because of the different return types.

From a quick glance, I think about the best you can do is have a shared function which accepts the SQL string and parameter array, and runs the prepare and execute commands, and returns the result object. For example:

```
class ActionWires
{
  public static function _checkExistDate($array){
    try{
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM wires WHERE fdate = ?";
        $state = self::runSQL($sql, $array);
        return $state->fetch()?true:false;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "database connection fail".$e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
  }

  public static function _showWires($array){
    try{
        $sql = "SELECT id,wname,fdate,fname,fpath,caption,category FROM wires WHERE fdate = ?";
        $state = self::runSQL($sql, $array);
        return $state->fetchAll();
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "database connection fail".$e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
  }
  private static function runSQL($sql, $paramList)
  {
        $state = pdoConnect::_connect() ->prepare($sql);
        $state->execute($paramList);
        return $state;
  }
}
```

But it only saves you a couple of lines.